# What is the usage of Assert.Equals?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am working on Unit Testing for my current project and came across something odd. The .Net UnitTesting library has both Assert.Equals and Assert.AreEqual. The [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.equals.aspx) for Assert.Equals say to use Assert.AreEqual to compare two objects, but gives no reason as to why to do so over Assert.Equals. Can somebody explain when you should use Assert.Equals in unit testing, if ever and the difference between Assert.Equals and Assert.AreEqual?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.Equals() exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489117/why-does-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-unittesting-assert-equals-exist)

Comment: Do you first of all understand what `Assert.Equals` does or means..? it checks to make sure 2 `objects are Equal` the `?' makes Objects `Nullable` which if you play around with things such as `DateTime, int` for example and try to set something like `var myInt = null`; it will fail but setting `var myInt? = null;` will make the integer nullable this should lead you to answer your own question

Comment: even more important I think that you should be asking when to use `.Equals` vs `==` there is a difference.. one checks `objects` while the other checks `values`

Comment: Yes I know .Equals vs ==, I did not make the connection that the Assert.Equals is the inherited from object. That clears a lot up, thanks.

Comment: This question was closed for the wrong reason. It is constructive, as it raises a non-obvious design question that help with correct application of the `Assert` class. However, it is a duplicate as previously noted.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`Assert.Equals` is just the `Equals` method inherited from `object`. It has nothing to do with unit testing, and in fact, has no use.

---

To be more precise, `Assert.Equals` is exactly the same as `Object.Equals`. `Object.Equals` has a use.

However, if you're using `Assert.Equals`, then  you're probably confusing it with `Assert.AreEqual`, and you want to stop using it.

Comment: "nothing to do with unit testing" - fine... but "in fact, has no use" is perhaps misleading.

Comment: What use does it have? Comparing instances of the `Assert` class?

Comment: I would argue it does have no use on the Assert class which is static.

Comment: @JohnSaunders it's use is simply ["Determines whether the specified object instances are considered equal."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w4hkze5k.aspx). Agree it has nothing to do with testing, but it's use is clearly stated.