# Unit testing ExceptionFilterAttribute

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to unit test my exception filter code.  I can validate the exception, but I can't seem to find the exception message to validate in the unit test.  Here is my code...

```
public class ExceptionHandlingAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is TimeoutException)
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, context.Exception.Message);
            return;
        }
        if (context.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, context.Exception.Message);
            return;
        }

        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Unable to process your request.");
    }
}
```

Unit Test Code

```
[Theory, MemberData("ExceptionData")]
    public void OnExceptionTests(Exception ex, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var actionContext = InitializeActionContext(request);
        var httpActionExectuedContext = new HttpActionExecutedContext(actionContext, ex);

        var exceptionHandlingAttribute = new ExceptionHandlingAttribute();
        exceptionHandlingAttribute.OnException(httpActionExectuedContext);
        Assert.Equal(actionContext.Response.StatusCode, statusCode);
        Assert.Equal(actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase, ex.Message);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<object[]> ExceptionData
    {
        get
        {

            return new[]
            {
                new object[] { new TimeoutException("My timeout message."), HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout }                   
            };
        }
    }
```

My problem is : Assert.Equal(actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase, ex.Message);

When I try to look at it in the watch window, I can't seem to find "My Timeout message" in the response.

UPDATE:

actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Request Timeout"

ex.Message = "My timeout message"

Comment: Can you show some code from your Response class as it relates to your ReasonPhrase member?

Comment: Also one issue you may be having it according to microsoft's [Asser.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.equals.aspx) documentation Assert.Equals compares objects not strings. I could be wrong about this but if your trying to compare strings you can do something like `actionContext.Response.ReasonPhrase.Equals(ex.Message)` but both the Assert.Equals and String.Equals methods as shown in my code snippet are both comparison methods and don't actually set values.

Comment: If I understand your first question, the Response class (context.Response = ...) is a native c# class.  Am I getting your question wrong?

Comment: FYI, when I run the test.  ReasonPhrase = "Request Timeout"  while ex.Message = "My timeout message".  I verified in xUnit that Assert.Equal(string, string) compares two strings.  I would assume that it means the value of two string variable strings are the same.

Comment: You got it right. In that case what type is ResponsePhrase? I could be wrong but I believe the Assert.equals is most likely your issue. Assert.Equals as stated above compares object types not strings or strings to objects. It would either always return false of throw an exception when trying to compare the two types. I would check out this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749487/what-is-the-usage-of-assert-equals) the answer sheds some light on Assert.equals that may be useful.

Comment: I'll check it out.  I wish I could find a bit more documentation on xUnit.  Is that thread for xUnit, it looks like the built in .Net unit testing framework.

Comment: Here is some resources I found: [An Introduction to xUnit.net for ASP.NET MVC Developers](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/06/30/an-introduction-to-the-xunit-net-testing-framework-for-asp-net-mvc-developers) and [How do I use xUnit.net?](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUse&referringTitle=Home) Possibly simple resources but they are resources non the less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message portion of the `CreateErrorResponse` isn't a property, you have to read the content to get the value.  Here's what I did...

```
var responseContent = await actionContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

After reading, responseContent now had:

```
{ "message" : "My timeout message." }
```